# How To Convert List Into DataTable For SQlBulkCopy

Tags: c#, sql, sqlbulkcopy

I have an object class which I cobvert into a List. I would like to convert the class into a list, so I can do a SQLBulkCopy, as my current method takes long to write data intop SQL database table.

```
class ExtractedInfo
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Client { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
List<ExtractedInfo> extractedList = new List<ExtractedInfo>(); 

try
            {

            Console.WriteLine("Writing to DB");

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionStringPMT))
            {
                conn.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd =
       new SqlCommand(
       "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [FileTrckT] WHERE Path = @Path) " +
       "INSERT INTO [FileTrckT] (Date, Client, Path, DateAddedToDb, FileName) " +  // dont forget to add "DateAddedToDb" on live code
       "VALUES (@Date, @Client, @Path, @DateAddedToDb, @FileName)");// dont forget to add " @DateAddedToDb" on live code
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", DbType.DateTime);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Client", DbType.String);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Path", DbType.String);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(@"DateAddedToDb",DbType.DateTime); //uncomment on live code 
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@FileName", DbType.String);

                foreach (var extractedRecord in extractedList)
                {   
                    cmd.Parameters[0].Value = extractedRecord.Date;
                    cmd.Parameters[1].Value = extractedRecord.Client;
                    cmd.Parameters[2].Value = extractedRecord.Path;
                    cmd.Parameters[3].Value = DateTime.Now;  //uncomment on live code 
                    cmd.Parameters[4].Value = extractedRecord.Path.Substring(extractedRecord.Path.LastIndexOf("/")+1);


                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                conn.Close();
            }
        } catch(Exception ex)
        {   
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Error occured whilst inserting data into sql table FiletrckT");
            log.Info("Error occured whilst inserting data into sql table FiletrckT");
                log.Error(DateTime.Now + ": " + ex.Message.ToString());
        }

        }

        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " " + ex.Message.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

A better option is to use [FastMember's](https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member) ObjectReader to create an IDataReader on top of the collection or IEnumerable. This way you avoid doubling memory usage by copying everything into a DataTable.

From the repo's samples:

```
using(var bcp = new SqlBulkCopy(connection)) 
using(var reader = ObjectReader.Create(myList, "Id", "Name", "Description")) 
{ 
   bcp.DestinationTableName = "SomeTable"; 
   bcp.WriteToServer(reader); 
}
```

You don't need to pass a field list if you want to export all fields.

The library is available [through NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FastMember/)

If you want to create a DataTable for other reasons, you can use MoreLINQ's [ToDataTable](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/ToDataTable.cs). It works the same as `ToList` or `ToArray` but generates a DataTable. The full MoreLINQ library is available through [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/). Individual extensions are available as code packages, eg ToDataTable's source is [available here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MoreLinq.Source.MoreEnumerable.ToDataTable/)

**UPDATE**

The `ExtractedInfo` class doesn't seem to match the fields of the `FileTrckT` table. This can be fixed by adding a `Select` call that converts the `ExtractedInfo` objects to the form expected by the table, eg:

```
var itemsToAdd= from it in extractedList
                select new { Date= DateTime.Parse(it.Date), //Or ParseExact
                             it.Client,
                             it.Path,
                             DateAddedToDb = DateTime.Now,
                             FileName = it.Path.Substring(it.Path.LastIndexOf("/")+1)
                            };
var fields=new []{"Date", "Client", "Path","DateAddedToDb","FileName"};

using(var bcp = new SqlBulkCopy(connection)) 
using(var reader = ObjectReader.Create(itemsToAdd, fields)) 
{ 
   bcp.DestinationTableName = "FileTrckT"; 
   bcp.WriteToServer(reader); 
}
```

Comment: This gives an error of: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.IDisposable' to 'System.Data.IDataReader'

Comment: @user8155123 only if you *didn't* pass a List to the reader. The samples work, I use this code to import 50K rows per day

Comment: @user8155123 the code compiles and runs just fine. What did you try?

Comment: @user8155123 I already posted an example using *your* code. The first example *also* shows passing a list to the `ObjectReader.Create()` method

Comment: Thanks, I did a small mistake on my side... It works

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out a way of not having duplicate data. Coz I need to make field Path as my primary key

Comment: @user8155123 this has nothing to do with *SqlBulkCopy*. If you suspect there may be duplicates in the source data you need to clean it *before* inserting it, eg by grouping by path and selecting only one record per group. If you suspect there may be records with that path already, *don't* load the data into the final table. Load them into a staging table and merge the tables, either with the `MERGE` command or `UPDATE/INSERT`

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own generic conversion method, like this for example:

```
private DataTable ConvertToDatatable<T>(IList<T> data)
{
    var props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in props)
        table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);
    foreach (T item in data)
    {
        DataRow row = table.NewRow();
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in props)
            row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;
        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    return table;
}
```

or an extension method:

```
static class MyExtenstions
{
    public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IList<T> data)
    {
        var props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in props)
            table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);
        foreach (T item in data)
        {
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in props)
                row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        return table;
    }
}
```